# How to implement the 'datepicker' correctly using swift when adding the multiple entries to server?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, datepicker

**Aim: ** To show latest apple calendar type of date picker(inline) in app when user wants to select the date.[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsmpY.png)

**Scenario:****
The user can input multiple entries (maximum 3) the exercise(suryanamaskar). These multiple entries has two functions

- 1.date-picker and
- 2.number entry(number of 'suryanamaskar')
- When user clicks on the date-picker button. the date picker shows up (.inline). Each entry fetches the post API call that saves the 'suryanamaskar' count entry on server.

**What is the issue:** I tried to implement the date-picker using and few UI frames : .inline
I replaced the date-picker completely and implemented ".wheels" that works fine.

The datepicker is show up correctly first time. But when the user tried to add other entry or press the date entry buttton . The datepicker gets cut and is not properly visible. [This is how it looks when user clicks on datepicker button second time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJahp.png).

**What my code looks like:**

> 

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire

struct surynamaskarStruct {
    var date: String
    var count: String
}

class AddSuryaNamskarCountVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    var surynamaskarData: [surynamaskarStruct] = [
        surynamaskarStruct(date: "Date", count: "0"),
        surynamaskarStruct(date: "Date", count: "0"),
        surynamaskarStruct(date: "Date", count: "0")
    ]
    
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var lblMember: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnMember: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var familyMemberHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    var viewPicker : UIView!
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    
    var btnIndex : Int!
    var strMemberId : String!
    var dicMember = [[String:Any]]()
    
    lazy var loader : UIActivityIndicatorView = {
        let indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .large)
        indicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        return indicator
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        if self.dicMember.count > 0 {
            self.strMemberId = self.dicMember[0]["id"] as? String
            self.lblMember.text = self.dicMember[0]["name"] as? String
            self.familyMemberHeightConstraint.constant = 90
        } else {
            self.familyMemberHeightConstraint.constant = 0
        }
        
        view.addSubview(loader)
        loader.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            loader.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            loader.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        navigationBarDesign(txt_title: "Record Suryanamskar", showbtn: "back")
    }
    
    @IBAction func onMemberClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PickerTableViewWithSearchViewController") as! PickerTableViewWithSearchViewController
        vc.selectedItemCompletion = {dict in
            self.lblMember.text = dict["name"] as? String
            self.strMemberId = dict["id"] as? String
        }
        vc.dataSource = dicMember
        vc.strNavigationTitle = "Family Member"
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    @IBAction func onCancelClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
    
    @IBAction func onSaveClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        var arrData = [[String:Any]]()
        for arr in surynamaskarData {
            if arr.date != "Date" && arr.count != "0" {
                var dict = [String : Any]()
                dict["date"] = arr.date
                dict["count"] = arr.count
                arrData.append(dict)
            }
        }
        
        if arrData.count > 0 {
            self.saveSuryaNamskarCountDataAPI(arrData)
            
   ////static controller to directly update the suryanamaskar chart instead of going back and then getting updated suryanamaskar
            
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title:APP.title, message: "Suryanamaskar has been saved successfully!", preferredStyle:.alert)

            let Action = UIAlertAction.init(title: "Ok", style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in
                // Write Your code Here
                
                let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SuryaNamskarVC") as! SuryaNamskarVC
                vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen
        //        vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.crossDissolve
                self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

            alertController.addAction(Action)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
           //// Till here for alert controller. if not implemented, updated suryanamaskar will happen only once user goes back and comes back to suryanamaskarVC
            
            
        }
        
//        else {
//            showAlert(title: APP.title, message: "Please select date and count before Save")
//        }

    }
    
    // MARK: - DatePicker functions
    func showDatePicker(){
        
        viewPicker = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: self.view.frame.height - 380, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 380))
        viewPicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        viewPicker.clipsToBounds = true
        // Posiiton date picket within a view
        datePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 200)
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        datePicker.minimumDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -2, to: Date())
        datePicker.maximumDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: 0, to: Date())
        
        datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
        } else {
            if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
                datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }

            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
      

        // Add an event to call onDidChangeDate function when value is changed.
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AddMemberStep1VC.datePickerValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        datePicker.center.x = self.view.center.x
        
        //ToolBar
        var toolbar = UIToolbar();
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50))
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "done".localized, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(donedatePicker));
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "cancel".localized, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelDatePicker));
        
        toolbar.setItems([doneButton,spaceButton,cancelButton], animated: false)
        
        //        txtDate.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        //        txtDate.inputView = datePicker
        
        self.viewPicker.addSubview(toolbar)
        
        self.viewPicker.addSubview(datePicker)
        self.viewPicker.clipsToBounds = true
        self.view.addSubview(self.viewPicker)
        
    }
    
    @objc func datePickerValueChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker){
        // Create date formatter
        let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        // Set date format
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        // Apply date format
        let _: String = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
        //        print("Selected value \(selectedDate)")
    }
    
    @objc func donedatePicker(){
        
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        let strDate = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        surynamaskarData[btnIndex].date = strDate
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        self.viewPicker.isHidden = true
    }
    
    @objc func cancelDatePicker(){
        self.viewPicker.isHidden = true
    }
    
    @objc func onAddMoreClicked() {
        print("AddMore Button Pressed")
        for i in surynamaskarData {
            if i.date == "Date" || i.count == "0" || i.count == "" {
                showAlert(title: APP.title, message: "Please select date and count before AddMore")
                return
            }
        }
        surynamaskarData.append(surynamaskarStruct(date: "Date", count: "0"))
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    @objc func onDateClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        btnIndex = sender.tag
        view.endEditing(true)
        if self.viewPicker == nil {
            self.showDatePicker()
        } else {
            if self.viewPicker.isHidden == true {
                self.showDatePicker()
            } else {
                self.viewPicker.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    @objc func onDeleteClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        surynamaskarData.remove(at: sender.tag)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if self.viewPicker != nil {
            if self.viewPicker.isHidden == false {
                self.viewPicker.isHidden = false
            }
        }
    }
    
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField.text == "" {
            textField.text = "0"
        }
        surynamaskarData[textField.tag].count = textField.text ?? "0"
    }
    
    func json(from object:Any) -> String? {
        guard let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: object, options: []) else {
            return nil
        }
        return String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    }
    
    
    
    func saveSuryaNamskarCountDataAPI(_ data : [[String:Any]]) {
        var parameters: [String: Any] = [:]
        parameters["surynamaskar"] = self.json(from: data)
        parameters["member_id"] = self.strMemberId // _appDelegator.dicDataProfile![0]["member_id"] as? String

        print(parameters)
//          APIUrl.save_suryanamaskar
        //live API only
        //"https://myhss.org.uk/api/v1/suryanamaskar/save_suryanamaskar_count"
        loader.startAnimating()
        let url = URL(string: APIUrl.save_suryanamaskar)!
        AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
          .validate()
          .responseJSON { response in
            self.loader.stopAnimating()
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let response):
              print(response)
                let jsonData = JSON(response)
                if let status = jsonData["status"].int
                {
                    if status == 1
                    {
                        let strMessage : String = jsonData["message"].rawValue as! String
                       print(strMessage)

                        // create the alert
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: APP.title, message: strMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                        // add an action (button)
                        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok".localized, style: .default, handler: { action in
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.dismiss(animated: true)
                            }
                        })
                        alert.addAction(ok)
                        // show the alert
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                    } else {
                        if let strError = jsonData["message"].string {
                            showAlert(title: APP.title, message: strError)
                        }
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
              print(error.localizedDescription)
                showAlert(title: APP.title, message: error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension AddSuryaNamskarCountVC : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return surynamaskarData.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: AddSuryaNamskarCountTVCell.cellIdentifier) as! AddSuryaNamskarCountTVCell
        cell.btnDate.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.btnDate.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.onDateClick(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
                
        cell.btnCancel.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.btnCancel.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.onDeleteClick(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        cell.lblDate.text = surynamaskarData[indexPath.row].date
        cell.txtCount.text = surynamaskarData[indexPath.row].count
        cell.txtCount.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.txtCount.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 60.0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let viewFooter = UIView()
        viewFooter.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGray5
        let size = tableView.frame.size
        let addMoreButton = UIButton()
        addMoreButton.setTitle("+ Add More", for: .normal)
        addMoreButton.setTitleColor(Colors.txtAppDarkColor, for: .normal)
        addMoreButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: 50)
        addMoreButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onAddMoreClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
        viewFooter.addSubview(addMoreButton)
        return viewFooter
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Changing the Co-ordinates works:
Following co-orinates fixes the calender view for this issue.**

```
 func showDatePicker(){
    
    viewPicker = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: self.view.frame.height - 500, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 500))
    viewPicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    viewPicker.clipsToBounds = true
    // Posiiton date picket within a view
    datePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 500)
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
    datePicker.minimumDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -2, to: Date())
    datePicker.maximumDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: 0, to: Date())
    
    datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
    } else {
        if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
            datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }

        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
  

    // Add an event to call onDidChangeDate function when value is changed.
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AddMemberStep1VC.datePickerValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    datePicker.center.x = self.view.center.x
    
    //ToolBar
    var toolbar = UIToolbar();
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50))
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "done".localized, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(donedatePicker));
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "cancel".localized, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelDatePicker));
    
    toolbar.setItems([doneButton,spaceButton,cancelButton], animated: false)
    
  
    
    self.viewPicker.addSubview(toolbar)
    
    self.viewPicker.addSubview(datePicker)
    self.viewPicker.clipsToBounds = true
    self.view.addSubview(self.viewPicker)
    
}
```